# Can a vector field undefined in a point be conservative?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

If i had a vector field $F$ defined in $R^3-\{\vec 0\}$ can it still be conservative?

If so, with what proof can I prove it?

Comment: Yes, why not? Just take any conservative field and pretend that it's not defined at $0$.

Comment: Isn't the gravity field of a point mass a standard example of such a vector field? The existence of a potential always mentions the domain also.

Comment: Doesn't this have something to do with the De Rham cohomology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conservative means its curl vanishes. Independent of path means the line integral depends only on the endpoints of the path. The two notions are equivalent in the case that we consider a vector field defined on a simply connected region. For example a region in the plane with no missing point, or a region in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that doesn't have a line removed (one dimensional singularity).

Conversely, in the plane with a point removed, or $\mathbb{R}^3$ with a line removed, a vector field can be conservative but not independent of path (paths that wind on one side of the singularity can have different line integral than paths on the other).

Similarly, a vector field in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be divergenceless, or it can be "independent of surface". The two notions are equivalent for vector fields defined in a region of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with no zero-dimensional singularity removed.

Conversely, in a region with a point removed (and this is the question you asked), surface integral can depend on which surface you choose.

Note that you ask about conservativity, but I think what you really want to ask is about "independence of surface".

Comment: Thanks, although I'm afraid this goes a little beyond my knowledge with "divergenceless and independance of surface".
With my question I wanted to go on "path independence" in a region in $R^3$ with a point removed.
However, I learned something new with this!

Comment: @BadEnglishSorry Yes, "independent of surface" is not a feature of vector fields that is mentioned in a vector calculus course. I only brought it up because it is relevant to the case that you asked about, namely a vector field with a point singularity, whereas conservative/independent of path is not.